# Return date after each month cut off date in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have encountered this situation where I need to return a specific date for each cut off automatically. The cut off will be 5 days before each month.

Desire output :

Start from Jan 1, the calculation of transaction will be between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-26
eg. from this period there are 100 transactions from 10 users.

Then the date will automatically start again between 2023-01-27 and 2023-02-23
eg. from this period there are 200 transactions from 20 users.
and so on..

So, basically the data will returns on each cut off

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please share sample data and desired output.

Comment: I put additional desire for the ouput.. Thank you

Comment: It will be easy if it is put in a tabular format